# How to use BjyProfiler in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

In my ZF2 application, I want to profile my database queries to browser console. I came across BjyProfiler to do so. I did all configuration as documented here: ["BjyProfiler at github"](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler). Everything is fine, but still I am not able to profile the database queries to browser console. Unfortunately I found no any document which would explains uses of BjyProfiler. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

BjyProfiler does not provide mechanisms for transmitting or storing query profile data, as this is outside the scope of the current module (as of 2012/10/23, at least).  If you wish to store (ie: to database or file) or transmit (ie: to browser console such as Chrome Developer Tools or FireBug) you will need to implement this yourself.

The [ZendDeveloperTools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) module has integration with BjyProfiler, but is currently limited to counting and aggregate timing of queries.  The ZF2 Doctrine ORM module ([DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule)) provides per-query profiling data to ZendDeveloperTools, and this is something that should be replicated for those using Zend\Db instead of Doctrine.

- Collector: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineORMModule/Collector/SQLLoggerCollector.php
- Toolbar view: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/view/zend-developer-tools/toolbar/doctrine-orm.phtml

Comment: Thanks Adam for your kind attention. I will go through ZendDeveloperTools module and will back to you in short. Anyways, I had success to configure BjyProfiler and now able to log the database queries in conjunction with Logger and FirePHP.

Comment: How did you do manage to log the db queries, Hanmant? Could you post it here for further reference?